# How to list all the branches of git repository, the latest updates on each, and state of local branches?

Tags: git

My main server storing my repositories crashed, and I want to restore them all their branches from the working copies. What I need to do now for each working copy is to list all the branches, list the ones with the latest updates, and find out for each branch whether the remotes have been fetched or not.

So for each working copy I need something like this.

```
repo name | location(directory) | branch name | date of last update | date of local copy | local up to date
```

`date of last update` is the date the server version was updated and `date of local copy` means the date on which the local copy was fetched. Commits to it may not have been pushed or it may be out of sync with the remote.

What script of git command can I run to get this information.

Comment: Some of the information is in `git branch -av` and `git remote show origin`. I hope that helps.